# up directive not working when dhcp is selected in /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0

Tags: linux-networking, dhcp, multicast

I have to add the multicast route, that is needed when no default gateway is configured. Mono needs this in order to join multicast groups. The configuring is done in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0`

Now the peculiar thing is:

If `eth0` is configured with a static IP it works:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.200
netmask 255.255.255.0
up ip route add 224.0.0.0/4 dev eth0
```

If `eth0` is configured to `dhcp`, `ip route` is not called:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
up ip route add 224.0.0.0/4 dev eth0
```

I tried a shell script writing a timestamp into a file in the `up` line but that does not get called either. So it seems to be the script not being called rather than the `ip route` command failing or getting overridden.

The systems in question are `debian` `stretch`, `buster`. This is running on embedded units with a readonly root partition.

Am I missing something here, why does it work with static config but not with dhcp?

To avoid the XY problem, is there a different method maybe to add said route at startup?

Comment: reproducing a setup equivalent to yours in buster (just in a LXC container) shows the route added with a dhcp setting. It can be seen without script with `ifup -v eth0` which will show commands executed. Maybe your embedded environment is different enough to deviate from default behavior?

Comment: Thanks, `-v` helped to understand the issue. In fact there's a `dhcpcd` error, resulting in `ifup` terminating at the `dhcp` command and not executing any `up` command thereafter.